# Run cucumber test from hooks file

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, cucumber, hook

Is there a way to start a scenario from inside of the hooks file. In the After hook I am grabbing the line of the scenario that failed and the file or feature that the scenario is in and formatted it so that I can run that line in the cmd and it will run just the failed scenario.

Example: features\homepage.feature:8 environment='http://stage.homepage.local/'

Now I need help running this in the After hook on a failed scenario

```
After() do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
    #code here w/ cucumber features\homepage.feature:8 environment='http://stage.homepage.local/'
  end
end
```

Can this even be done?

Answer (score 0):

We can run the scenario from hooks file. System is the keyword that used to execute the given command in the console.

Try the below code

> After() do |scenario|
>
> if scenario.failed?
>
> ```
> run_cmd = "cucumber features\homepage.feature:8 environment='http://stage.homepage.local/'"
>
> system run_cmd
> ```
>
> end
>
> end